# A question on the real root of a polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, polynomials

For $n\geq 1$, given a polynomial
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   f(x)=&\frac{2+(x+3)\sqrt{-x}}{2(x+4)}(\sqrt{-x})^n+\frac{2-(x+3)\sqrt{-x}}{2(x+4)}(-\sqrt{-x})^n \\
   &+\frac{x+2+\sqrt{x(x+4)}}{2(x+4)}\left ( \frac{x+\sqrt{x(x+4)}}{2} \right )^n+\frac{x+2-\sqrt{x(x+4)}}{2(x+4)}\left ( \frac{x-\sqrt{x(x+4)}}{2} \right )^n.
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation*}
Using Mathematic $12.3$, when $n$ is large enough, we give the distribution of the roots of $f(x)$ in the complex plane as follows

[image]

In this figure, we can see that the closure of the real roots of $f(x)$ may be $\left [ -4,0 \right ]$.

So we have the following question

**Question:** all roots of $f(x)$ are real? It seems yes! But we have no way of proving it.

Comment: Is it also true that $f_n$ for small $n$ have roots only in the real segment $[0,4]$? Also the explicit (polynomial - type) form of $f_n$ for small $n$ could be helpful

Comment: It seems to me that the change of variable $x=2\cos(\theta)-2$ transforms your polynomial into a simple trigonometric expression, but I am too lazy to work it out.

Comment: Are the roots of $f_n$ and $f_{n-1}$ intertwined? By the way, no need to compute roots numerically, using Sturm's Theorem you can check that all roots are in $[0,4]$ using only algebra.

Comment: Why is there a denominator of $2(x+4)$ in every term of $f$? It would seem polite to remove that common factor.

Comment: @HenriCohen, On the first glance this substitution gives $f_{4k} = 2^{2k}(\cos\theta - 1)^{2k}(1 + 2\sum_{m = 1}^k (-1)^m\cos(m\theta))^2$. Some similar relation also seem to hold for $ 8k + 2$ and $8k + 6$. However I struggle to guess the pattern for odd numbers

Comment: How large n have you tried? I had a similar-looking conjecture, which failed at n=16...

Comment: @Per Alexandersson I tried to $n=200$, it still holds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that we have $x = - (t + 1/t)^2 = -t^2 - 1/t^2 - 2$ for some $t \in \mathbb{C}$. Then
$$
\sqrt{-x} = t + \frac{1}{t} = \frac{t^2 + 1}{t},\quad x + 4 = -\left(t - \frac{1}{t}\right)^2, \quad \sqrt{x(x + 4)} = t^2 - \frac{1}{t^2},
\\
x + \sqrt{x(x + 4)} = -2\left(1 + \frac{1}{t^2}\right) = -2\frac{1 + t^2}{t^2}, \quad x - \sqrt{x(x + 4)} = -2(1 + t^2)
$$
Consequently, we get
$$
f_n(x)= \tilde f_n(t) = \frac{(1 + t^2)^n(t^{n + 2} - 1)^2}{t^{2n}(t^2 - 1)^2},\quad\text{if } n\text{ is even},
\\
f_n(x) = \tilde f_n(t) = -\frac{(1 + t^2)^n(1 - t^{n -1})(1 - t^{n+5})}{t^{2n}(t^2 - 1)^2},\quad\text{if } n\text{ is odd}.
$$
Hence the only roots of $\tilde f_n$ are the suitable roots of unity and the roots of $f_n$ are all in the real segment $[-4, 0]$ and their closure is the whole segment for large $n$.

Comment: Thanks, but the interval of the root of $f_n$ seems to be $\left [ -4,0 \right ]$?

Comment: Oh, you right! That is a misprint, fixed now

Comment: And I have a question for this answer, how to guarantee $\sqrt{x(x+4)}=t^2-\frac{1}{t^2}$ rather than $\sqrt{x(x+4)}=-t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}$, and so on.

Comment: Formula is symmetric with respect to $\sqrt{x(x + 4)}$ and $-\sqrt{x(x + 4)}$, so it does not matter how to extract the square root. As for $\sqrt{-x}$, for even $n$ there is $\sqrt{-x}^{n} = (-x)^{n/2}$ and for odd $n$ there is $\sqrt{-x}^{n + 1} = (-x)^{(n + 1)/2}$, hence one can actually make the substitution without computing $\sqrt{-x}$

Comment: That's nice! Thanks for your careful answer. :)

Answer (score 8):

**EDITED.** First let us define
$$g_n(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n-k\choose k} x^{n-k}.$$
Then empirically,
$$\eqalign{f_{2n}(x) &= g_n(x)^2\cr
   f_{4n+1}(x) &= g_{2n+2}(x)g_{2n-1}(x)\cr
   f_{4n+3}(x) &= g_{2n}(x)g_{n+1}(x)h_{n+2}(x)\cr}$$
where $h_n(x)$ is a [Lucas polynomial](http://oeis.org/A034807).
I think it should be possible to prove these formulas using the [recurrence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440962/a-question-on-the-real-root-of-a-polynomial/441115#comment1137548_440975) $f_n(x)=xf_{n−1}(x)+x^2f_{n−3}(x)+x^2f_{n−4}(x)$. Then, as noted in [Ira Gessel's comment below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440962/a-question-on-the-real-root-of-a-polynomial/441115#comment1137991_441115), the desired properties of the roots of $f_{2n}(x)$ and $f_{4n+1}(x)$ follow from the properties of the Chebyshev polynomials. Presumably the roots of Lucas polynomials are also well understood, but I'm not so familiar with them.

Comment: So $f_{2n}(x) = (-x)^n U_n(\sqrt{-x}/2)^2$, where $U_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. Most likely there is some sort of expression for $f_{2n+1}(x)$ in terms of Chebyshev  polynomials but it will not be as simple.

Comment: I also just discovered that the connection between the Lucas polynomials and $T_n$ is given in Section 6.4 of [On the characteristic polynomial of Cartan matrices and Chebyshev polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6620) by Pantelis A. Damianou.

Comment: Thanks for Timothy Chow and Ira Gessel's answers, amazing construction! At first, we tried to use the Sturm sequence to prove the real zeros, but it seem to be impossible :(

Comment: The OEIS page for the Lucas polynomials uses a different normalization. Here is a corrected version of my comment on them. The polynomials $h_n(x)$ in Tim's answer have the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n(x) y^n = (2-xy)/(1-xy-xy^2)$. 
They are given by $h_0(x)=2$ and 
$$h_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}\frac{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{k}x^{n-k}$$
for $n>0$.
They are related to the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind $T_n(x)$ by $$h_n(x) = 2(-\sqrt{-x})^{n} T_n(\sqrt{-x}/2)$$
so their roots can be determined from the roots of the Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: In the process of deleting his incorrect comment, Ira Gessel also deleted the math.SE link, [Algorithm for computing Hadamard product of two rational generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2520025). This is another way to prove the correctness of the empirically derived formulas: take Hadamard products of (suitably rescaled) generating functions for the Chebyshev polynomials, and confirm that they give you the generating function of the $f$ polynomials.

Answer (score 6):

(This is a comment, not an answer.)

If $f_n(x)$ is your polynomial, starting with $f_0(x)=1$, then
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) y^n = 
   \frac{1-xy+x^2y^2+x^2y^3}{(1+xy^2)(1-xy-xy^2)}
   = 1 + \frac{x^2y^2(1+y)^2}{(1+xy^2)(1-xy-xy^2)}. $$
Also, I noticed that $f_n(x)-x f_{n-1}(x)-x f_{n-2}(x)$ only has one or two terms, so a recurrence is possible. That there are no positive real zeros follows from the fact that there are no negative coefficients. The rest of your question is another matter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm sorry that I forgot to indicate the $n \geq 1$. Based on your comment, then by the generating function of $f_n(x)$, we get the recurrence relation of $f_n(x)$, that is $f_n(x)=xf_{n-1}(x)+x^2f_{n-3}+x^2f_{n-4}$ (for $n \geq 5$).

Comment: But in this recurrence relation, we can't seem to be sure that $f_n(x)$ is all real roots.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof, using Maple calculations, of Tim Chow's empirical observations. We use Hadamard products of power series.  The Hadamard product (with respect to the variable $y$) is defined by
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n y^n *\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n y^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n b_n y^n.
$$
The Hadamard product of two rational power series is rational, and I did the following computations with a Maple program I wrote using the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3230621) .

For any power series $A(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n y^n$ and  integers $m$ and $i$, let
\begin{equation*}
A_{m,i}(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{mn+i}y^i,
\end{equation*}
where we take $a_n=0$ if $n<0$. Following Brendan McKay, we  define the generating function.
$$F=F(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) y^n = 
  1+\frac{x^{2} y^{2} \left(1+y \right)^{2}}{\left(1+x y^{2}\right) \left(1-xy-x y^{2}\right)}
$$
We also define generating functions for Timothy Chow's polynomials $g_n(x)$ and $h_n(x)$:
\begin{gather*}
G=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x) y^n = \frac{1}{1-xy-xy^2}\\
H=\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n(x) y^n = \frac{2-xy}{1-xy-xy^2}.
\end{gather*}
Then we want to prove
\begin{gather}
F_{2,0}=G*G\tag{1}\\
F_{4,1}=G_{2,2}*G_{2,-1}\tag{2}\\
F_{4,3}=G_{2,0}*G_{1,1}*H_{1,2}\tag{3}
\end{gather}
Multisections, can be computed by Hadamard products (or in other ways). For example,
$F(y)*y/(1-y^4) = yF_{4,1}(y^4)$. We find that
\begin{gather*}
F_{2,0} =\frac{1-x y }{\left(1+x y \right) \left(1-2xy -x^{2} y +x^{2} y^{2}\right)}\\
F_{4,1}=\frac{x^3y(1+3x+x^2 -x^2y)}{(1-x^2y)(1-(2x^2+4x^3+x^4) y +x^{4} y^{2})}\\
F_{4,3}=\frac{x^2(2+x -\left(3x^2+4x^3+x^4\right) y +x^{4} y^{2})}{(1-x^2y)(1-(2x^2+4x^3+x^4) y +x^{4} y^{2})}\\
G_{1,1}=\frac{x(1+y)}{1-xy-xy^2}\\
G_{2,-1}=\frac{xy}{1-2xy-x^2y+x^2y^2}\\
G_{2,0}=\frac{1-xy}{1-2xy-x^2y+x^2y^2}\\
G_{2,2}=\frac{x(1+x-xy)}{1-2xy-x^2y+x^2y^2}\\
H_{1,2}=\frac{x(2+x+xy)}{1-xy-xy^2}
\end{gather*}
We can then verify $(1)$–$(3)$ directly.

Answer (score 2):

(another comment, not an answer.)

Experimentally, with the following code

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
var('n', integer = True)

f = ( (2+(x+3) * sqrt(-x))/(2*(x+4)) *
      sqrt(-x)**n + ((2-(x+3) * sqrt(-x)) / (2*(x+4))) * (-sqrt(-x))**n +
      + (x+2+sqrt(x*(x+4)))/(2*(x+4)) *
        ( (x+sqrt(x*(x+4)))/2 )**n +
        (x+2-sqrt(x*(x+4)))/(2*(x+4)) *
        ( (x-sqrt(x*(x+4)))/2 )**n
        )
pprint(f)
for i in range(10):
   eq = simplify(f.subs(n,i))
   print ('========== n = ', i)
   pprint(eq)
   print ('have solutions')
   sols = solve(eq)
   pprint (sols)
   pprint ('approx. = ')
   pprint ([s.evalf() for s in sols])
```

we see the following:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
f_{0} = 1\\
f_{1} = 0\\
f_{2} = x^{2}\\
f_{3} = x^{2} \left(x + 2\right)\\
f_{4} = x^{2} \left(x^{2} + 2 x + 1\right)\\
f_{5} = x^{3} \left(x^{2} + 3 x + 1\right)\\
f_{6} = x^{4} \left(x^{2} + 4 x + 4\right)\\
f_{7} = x^{4} \left(x^{3} + 5 x^{2} + 7 x + 3\right)\\
f_{8} = x^{4} \left(x^{4} + 6 x^{3} + 11 x^{2} + 6 x + 1\right)\\
f_{9} = x^{5} \left(x^{4} + 7 x^{3} + 16 x^{2} + 13 x + 2\right)\\
\end{array}
$$

[image]

And it seems that already $f_9$ have some imaginary roots, albeit very small.
Do these imaginary roots really converge to 0 when $n\to \infty$ or they stay on the same magnitude ?

Comment: This looks like a calculation error of some type. $P(x) =  x^4 + 7x^3 + 16x^2 + 13x + 2$ has four real zeroes

Comment: hum... You are right. Softwares are not intelligent enough to simplify stuff. The roots of $f_9$ are -$ \frac{5}{3} + \frac{2 \sqrt{7} \sin{\left(- \frac{\operatorname{atan}{\left(3 \sqrt{3} \right)}}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6} \right)}}{3};
- \frac{5}{3} + \frac{2 \sqrt{7} \sin{\left(\frac{\operatorname{atan}{\left(3 \sqrt{3} \right)}}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6} \right)}}{3};
- \frac{5}{3} - \frac{2 \sqrt{7} \cos{\left(\frac{\operatorname{atan}{\left(3 \sqrt{3} \right)}}{3} \right)}}{3}$

Comment: If you compute more terms using the [recurrence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440962/a-question-on-the-real-root-of-a-polynomial/441092#comment1137548_440975) then the polynomials $f_n(x)$ seem to factor nicely; see [A054142](http://oeis.org/A054142) and [A145324](http://oeis.org/A145324) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Take the first two terms in your sum, and multiply by $x+4$, then
you get a sequence of polynomials which satisfy $P_n = -x P_{n-2}$,
and if you do the same for the last two terms, you get a sequence
determined by $Q_n = x Q_{n-1}+x Q_{n-2}$.
Now, $Q_n$ interlaces the roots of $Q_{n+1}$ so these are easy to show
are real-rooted. Same goes for $P_n$ and $P_{n+2}$.

So, perhaps one can combine these somehow in order to show that the sum is real-rooted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We have also tried this method, but the sign pattern of $P_n$ is $--++\cdots $, and the existing results cannot seem to get $P_n+Q_n \in RZ$